# Time output while sending data

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Trying to print time with every output of velocity but currently it shows the same time at every output. It doesnt change while running.

What im trying to get is a time for each time the program sends the velocity variable to the other raspberry so i can measure how fast the change of velocity happens.

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import pigpio
import datetime
#------------------------Definingfunctions and variables ------------------#
pi = pigpio.pi()
ct = datetime.datetime.now()
pi.set_mode(21,pigpio.INPUT)
pulseDegrees = 2*np.pi/38
T_old = 0
count = 0
def cbf(g ,L ,t):
    T_new = t
    global velocity, T_old
    velocity = pulseDegrees/(T_new-T_old)*(1/0.000001)
    print(str(velocity))
    print("time:-", ct)
    T_old = T_new

def sendData():
    conn.recv (1024)
    conn.send(str(velocity).encode('UTF-8'))
#--------------------------Communication--------------------#
# The units ipaddress
print ("Awaiting connection")
port=5555
s=socket.socket()
s.bind(('' ,port))

s.listen(1)
(conn,addr)=s.accept()
print ("Connected to " + str(addr))
#--------------------------Main loop--------------------#
cb = pi.callback(21,pigpio.RISING_EDGE, cbf)
while True:
    sendData ()
```

Comment: you call datetime.now() only once - but you'll have to update the value whenever you want to print the current time; e.g. change `print("time:-", ct)` to `print("time:-", datetime.datetime.now())`

Comment: Than you so much!